# what's the difference background-color and backgroundColor?

Tags: html, css

what's the difference background-color and backgroundColor? i can see the result is the same. however, which one should I use for best practice? Thanks.

Comment: backgroundColor = JavaScript and  background-color = CSS

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The CSS property is called `background-color`. This is what you should use in a stylesheet. You can also use uppercase letters because CSS is case-insensitive, but there needs to be an hyphen.

```css
#element {
  background-color: red;
}
```

If you want to get or set that property using JavaScript, you can then use

```js
element.style.getPropertyValue("background-color");
element.style.setProperty("background-color", "red");
element.style.setPropertyValue("background-color", "red");
```

However, it would be more convenient to be able to access it as a JS property. The problem is that the hyphen would be treated as a subtraction. To address that, the [`CSSStyleDeclaration` interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom/#the-cssstyledeclaration-interface) is extended by partial interfaces in order to allow to get or set the values of [supported CSS properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom/#supported-css-property) using IDL [camel-case attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom/#dom-cssstyledeclaration-camel-cased-attribute).

That means you can also use

```js
element.style.backgroundColor = "red";
element.style["backgroundColor"] = "red";
```

Comment: So basically all we have to do is remove the hyphen and capitalize the letter after the hyphe. For example I have a property called `http-equiv` in a `meta` tag, but I don't believe it's a CSS property. `x=document.createElement("meta"); x.httpEquiv="refresh";` works nicely. I have found this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Properties_Reference but it's only for CSS properties.

Answer (score 5):

`backgroundColor` is used by javascript to apply an inline style to an element. For example `document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";` will result in an inline style on an element `style="background-color: red;"`. So the end result is the same, but `backgroundColor` is the JS value that translates to `background-color` in CSS

Answer (score 3):

`background-color` is used in css.

`backgroundColor` is used by javascript for inline styles because javascript would interpret the hyphen from `background-color` as a subtraction operation.

In the end they come out with the same result but they are each for different uses.